# WP7 App Updating observable collections from service & updating UI

Tags: multithreading, wcf, windows-phone-7, location, observablecollection

Hi im making an app that trackers other users movements and uploads your own

I'm downloading collections from a service repeatably

I want to assigning the data to collections on the phone
doing stuff with these collections(such as triangulation of proximity) and calling these locations to update a map..

whats the best way to go about doing this, to avoid conflicts with access to the observable collections ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By avoiding conflicts I presume you mean threading issues? If that is the case, make sure you always use the Dispatcher to move work that updates the UI onto the UI thread:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => {
  myObservableCollection.Add(myDataItem);
});
```

You can obtain a reference to the Dispatcher from any UI control

Comment: Or you can get `System.Windows.Deployment.Current.Dispatcher` from pretty much anywhere.